# How can I minimize/iconify a JWindow in Java?

Tags: java, swing, minimize, jwindow

My app has a JWindow that needs to be minimized when the custom minimizer button clicked.
Please reply if anyone knows how to minimize a JWindow. I have searched a lot but couldn't find any suitable method to minimize.
I know how to minimize a JFrame. So please don't bother answering regarding JFrame.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the fact that a JWindow is not decorated with any control icons, no `setState` method is provided. One workaround is to allow your custom minimizer button to set the window visible as required:

```
public class JWindowTest extends JFrame {

    JWindow window = new JWindow();
    JButton maxMinButton = new JButton("Minimize Window");

    public JWindowTest() {
        setSize(300, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        maxMinButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (window.isVisible()) {
                    maxMinButton.setText("Restore Window");
                } else {
                    maxMinButton.setText("Minimize Window");
                }
                window.setVisible(!window.isVisible());
            }
        });

        add(maxMinButton);

        window.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 220);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(this);
        window.add(new JLabel("Test JWindow", JLabel.CENTER));
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JWindowTest().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I changed it a bit to match my own!

Answer (score 3):

I know you don't want to hear this, but the terrible truth is that there is no big difference between undecorated jframes (with setstate methods) and jwindows... :)

```
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame");
    f.setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: Thank you too for the info! Didn't know it!